# Lua commands , what do they do?

Tags: lua, torch

I am unfamiliar with lua. 
but the author of the article used lua.

can you help me understand what those two lines do:

what does 
`replicate(x,batch_size)` do?

what does `x = x:resize(x:size(1), 1):expand(x:size(1), batch_size)` do?

original source code can be found here
https://github.com/wojzaremba/lstm/blob/master/data.lua

Comment: it's right in the comment. you don't need to know Lua for that: "-- Stacks replicated, shifted versions of x_inp
-- into a single matrix of size x_inp:size(1) x batch_size.",    "-- Intentionally we repeat dimensions without offseting.
-- Pass over this batch corresponds to the fully sequential processing"

Comment: @Piglet replicated yeah, but replicated how? , shifted how? can you help with example? for instance, x_inp=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].  and say batch size =2. x should have size= (5,2) according to the code, but  x_inp has 11 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically boils down to simple maths and looking up a few functions in the torch manual.

Ok I'm bored so...

`replicate(x,batch_size)` as defined in https://github.com/wojzaremba/lstm/blob/master/data.lua

```
-- Stacks replicated, shifted versions of x_inp
-- into a single matrix of size x_inp:size(1) x batch_size.
local function replicate(x_inp, batch_size)
   local s = x_inp:size(1)
   local x = torch.zeros(torch.floor(s / batch_size), batch_size)
   for i = 1, batch_size do
     local start = torch.round((i - 1) * s / batch_size) + 1
     local finish = start + x:size(1) - 1
     x:sub(1, x:size(1), i, i):copy(x_inp:sub(start, finish))
   end
   return x
end
```

This code is using the [Torch](http://torch.ch/) framework.

`x_inp:size(1)` returns the size of dimension 1 of the [Torch tensor](https://cornebise.com/torch-doc-template/tensor.html#toc_0) (a potentially multi-dimensional matrix) `x_inp`.

See https://cornebise.com/torch-doc-template/tensor.html#toc_18

So `x_inp:size(1)` gives you the number of rows in `x_inp`. `x_inp:size(2)`, would give you the number of columns...

```
local x = torch.zeros(torch.floor(s / batch_size), batch_size)
```

creates a new two-dimensional tensor filled with zeros and creates a local reference to it, named `x`
The number of rows is calculated from `s`, `x_inp`'s row count and `batch_size`. So for your example input it turns out to be `floor(11/2) = floor(5.5) = 5`.

The number of columns in your example is 2 as `batch_size` is 2.

torch.

So simply spoken `x` is the 5x2 matrix

```
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

The following lines copy `x_inp`'s contents into `x`.

```
for i = 1, batch_size do
  local start = torch.round((i - 1) * s / batch_size) + 1
  local finish = start + x:size(1) - 1
  x:sub(1, x:size(1), i, i):copy(x_inp:sub(start, finish))
end
```

In the first run, `start` evaluates to 1 and `finish` to `5`, as `x:size(1)` is of course the number of rows of `x` which is `5`. `1+5-1=5`
In the second run, `start` evaluates to 6 and `finish` to `10`

So the first 5 rows of `x_inp` (your first batch) are copied into the first column of `x` and the second batch is copied into the second column of `x`

`x:sub(1, x:size(1), i, i)` is the sub-tensor of `x`, row 1 to 5, column 1 to 1 and in the second run row 1 to 5, column 2 to 2 (in your example). So it's nothing more than the first and second columns of `x`

See https://cornebise.com/torch-doc-template/tensor.html#toc_42

```
:copy(x_inp:sub(start, finish))
```

copies the elements from `x_inp` into the columns of `x`.

So to summarize you take an input tensor and you split it into batches which are stored in a tensor with one column for each batch.

So with `x_inp`

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and `batch_size = 2`

`x` is

```
0 5
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
```

Further:

```
local function testdataset(batch_size)
  local x = load_data(ptb_path .. "ptb.test.txt")
  x = x:resize(x:size(1), 1):expand(x:size(1), batch_size)
  return x
end
```

Is another function that loads some data from a file. This `x` is not related to the `x` above other than both being a tensor.

Let's use a simple example:

`x` being

```
1
2
3
4
```

and `batch_size = 4`

```
x = x:resize(x:size(1), 1):expand(x:size(1), batch_size)
```

First `x` will be resized to 4x1, read https://cornebise.com/torch-doc-template/tensor.html#toc_36

And then it is expanded to 4x4 by duplicating the first row 3 times.

Resulting in `x` being the tensor

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

read https://cornebise.com/torch-doc-template/tensor.html#toc_49